# How do I detect if wear/handheld Android devices are disconnected or connected using callbacks?

Tags: android, google-api, wear-os

I'm trying to work out how to get an update on my device that the paired device has connected or disconnected. What I need is funationality that used to be accomplished like this:

```
@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED");          
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
    Log.d(TAG, "PEER DISCONNECTED");
}
```

but that has since been deprecated and the docs say to use the CapabilityAPI, and the examples I have seen use WearableListenerService, but I am not able to use this because my class extends Fragment, so I can't extend WearableListenerService. Can someone show me how they achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to use WearableListenerService for CapabilityApi; you can register a CapabilityApi.CapabilityListener() in your activity; see this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html).

Comment: the scenario in the tutorial is, the wearable app discovers the phone app, using CapabilityListener to find out who can help to transcribe voice. I'm wondering how can the phone app discovers the wearable device. Can you elaborate on that? Thanks